# php login code not working

Tags: php, authentication

so i wrote this code for a login page in php

```
<?php 
function SignIn() {
    session_start(); //starting the session for user profile page
    if(!empty($_POST['username'])) //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.html, is it empty or have some text 
    {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register where Username = '$_POST[username]' AND Password = '$_POST[password]'") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if(!empty($row['Username']) AND !empty($row['Password'])) { 
            if($password = $row['Password']) {
                $_SESSION['Username'] = $row['Password'];
                echo "welcome    ".$row['Name']; 
            }
            if ($password != $row['Password']) {
                echo "Something went wrong!" ;
            }
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        SignIn(); 
}
?>
```

My problem is that while the login part works perfectly (when i give the right password) ,when i give a wrong password it doesn't show the message i set it to echo but shows a blank page instead....i tried so many times but no result...could someone please give me some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `IF` statement is setting `$password` to the `$row['password']` value:

```
if($password = $row['Password'])
```

When your second if statement starts, `$password` is the same as `$row['password']` and the condition equals false:

```
if($password != $row['Password'])
```

The solution is to change the first if statement to a comparative equals:

```
if($password == $row['Password'])
```

Notice there are two `=` symbols? This tells PHP to check that they are both the same value.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have missed out an = sign :

```
 if($password = $row['Password'])
```

as such you are not doing a comparison, but an assignment.  I expect this should be :

```
 if($password == $row['Password'])
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function SignIn() { 
 session_start(); //starting the session for user profile page
  if(!empty($_POST['username'])) //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.html, is it empty or have some text 
  {
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register where Username = '$_POST[username]' AND Password = '$_POST[password]'") or die(mysql_error()); 
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if(!empty($row['Username']) && !empty($row['Password'])) { 
        if($password == $row['Password'])
        {
            $_SESSION['Username'] = $row['Password'];
             echo "welcome   ".$row['Name']; 

        }
         else
            echo "Something went wrong!" ;
     }

    }

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

second if condition must be outside the first if condition..

you are also  assigning the password to`$_SESSION['Username']` instead of `$row['Username']` . i edited the code.. see below

```
<?php 
    function SignIn() {
        session_start(); //starting the session for user profile page
        if(!empty($_POST['username'])) //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.html, is it empty or have some text 
        {
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register where Username = '$_POST[username]' AND Password = '$_POST[password]'") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());

            if(!empty($row['Username']) AND !empty($row['Password'])) { 
            if($_POST['password'] = $row['Password'])
            $_SESSION['Username'] = $row['Username']; 
            echo "welcome   ".$row['Username']; 
            }

             if ($_POST['password'] != $row['Password']) {
               echo "Something went wrong!" ;
            }
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            SignIn(); 
    }


    ?>
```